# Looking for an example of a $\mathcal{L}$-expression

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, formal-languages

In a propositional language $\mathcal{L}$, give an example of an $\mathcal{L}$-expression which is not an $\mathcal{L}$-formula, but is not
ruled out by the results in either Problems 3 or 4. State, and prove by induction on formulas, a result which rules it out.

Prob 3: every $\mathcal{L}$-formula has the same number of left and right parenthesis.

Prob 4: in every $\mathcal{L}$-formula $s=c+1$, where $s$ is the number of proposition variables and $c$ is the number of binary connectives.

Comment: What does it mean "State, and by prove by induction on formulas, a result which rules it out"? Are you asking also for a proof of properties 3 and 4?

Comment: No - properties 3 and 4 hold. I want to find an expression that does not satisfy the requirements of being a formula for reasons other than 3 or 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p$ be a proposition variable in the language $\mathcal{L}$. Then, the $\mathcal{L}$-expressions $)p($ is not a $\mathcal{L}$-formula but it has the same number of left and right parenthesis, and moreover $s = c + 1$ because for such an $\mathcal{L}$-expression the number $s$ of variables is 1 and the number $c$ of binary connectives is $0$.

Comment: Incredible. Thank you very much.